# How to update the VMSS to use the existing LB in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

How to update the VMSS to use the existing LB in Azure
e.g. I have LB1 with 2 IIS webserver in Availability Set
Now i need to configure the auto scaling
created VMSS with existing IIS server Image but how to apply scaling with my existing LB1 as VMSS is creating the different LB.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate an existing LB with a scaleset however it cannot be done via the portal. Rather you need to use CLI or PowerShell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#create-a-scale-set-that-references-an-existing-azure-load-balancer

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the below script which I created for attaching a VMSS to an existing Internal Standard Load balancer.

Link: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/VMSS-with-Standard-ILB-4f231dfa